# Answers sorted by Activity or Newest render the exact same results

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I would expect that:

- Sorting by newest will show my most recent answers on top (**this works ok**)
- Sorting by activity will display my answers with the most recent votes on top (**this does not work**. The results displayed are exactly the same as sorting by newest. On my current case, this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/7391328/345490 should be listed on top when sorting by activity since this is the one with most recent activity; instead, I see the same results as sorting by newest)
- Sorting by votes will display answers with the highest votes first (**this works ok**)

---

In conclusion, sorting by newest should display the ones in which *I* have participated more recently on top. Sorting by activity should display the answers in which *others* have upvoted/downvoted my answers more recently on top.

Comment: Activity=counts edits as activity, not votes. Its useful to find out who changed what in a thread with 10 answers which just bumped itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oh I see the confusion here, voting does not count as activity on a post (it never has), activity is the last time the post was edited, or an answer was added to it (when talking about a question).  *The post* didn't change otherwise, just what someone else thought of it.

If activity counted votes (after we sorted out all the deadlocks!), we'd just see very old content bumped on the question activity pages non-stop...they don't need new eyes unless *something changed*, and score doesn't count for that.

Think of it this way: the score went from 3 to 4, is that news? no, not really. Ok same post, the editor clarified, added a link, maybe completely overhauled the answer, is *that* news? *yes*.

The profile is working exactly as it should, sorting on the last time a post was edited.  If you goal is to see what's the latest thing someone voted on...that's what the reputation tab is for: [here's yours](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345490/icarus?tab=reputation&sort=time).

Comment: I think it could be neat to see which questions/answers are being voted on recently.

Comment: @nick I thought that sorting by activity would display questions on which *my answers*, not anybody's answers, had received downvotes/upvotes more recently. But then again, reputation already serves this purpose. Thank you for clarifying.